# Creating HCatalog Schema from File

Tags: hadoop, hive, hcatalog

I have a csv file that containes about a thousand different columns I want to make this into a Hive table and a HCatalog schema without typing each field individually.. Is this possible? If so could someone point me in the right direction thanks.

Comment: Or better yet, load a table into Hive without defining a schema and set it to use the '$0' positional naming method it uses in Pig.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer going with a java program for this problem. Please make sure the CSV file header  is the required columns for hive or hcatalog table...                     Java comes with CSVReader which can read headers of the CSV file.add these headers  to an array list.                       Either make use of JDbc or Webhcat  to create tables on hive and hcatalog.                                                                       For jdbc iterate through the list while adding columns yo the table.                                                                                      Same approach can be followed for webhcat also.